# Display and Hide a Div using check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Single Factor Auhtentication]

My requirement is like,  If i am choosing single factor i can able to choose only one type of authentication mode. If any one of the authentication mode is chosen the corresponding div will be showed, In multiple factor I can able to select two authentication mode but if I am selecting two authentication modes only the first checked div get's displayed but the second checked div doesn't get's displayed. How to display both the div's when selecting 2 options.

[image: Multiple Factor]

I tried this:

```
    if ($('#chkOTP').is(':checked')) {
        $('#OTPMain').show();
    } else if ($('#chkVoicePrint').is(':checked')) {
        $('#VoicePrintEmailCampMain').show();
    } else if ($('#chkPersonInfo').is(':checked')) {
        $('#RandomAuthMain').show();
    } else if ($('#chkPastHis').is(':checked')) {
        $('#PastHistoryMain').show();
    } else if ($('#chkSQ').is(':checked')) {
        $('#SqQuestionMain').show();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post your code... not the description of what you want

Comment: We are not here to do your work. We help you, but we need to see what you have so far (so post some code, please).

Comment: if($('#chkOTP').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#OTPMain').show();
    }else if($('#chkVoicePrint').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#VoicePrintEmailCampMain').show();
    }else if($('#chkPersonInfo').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#RandomAuthMain').show();
    }else if($('#chkPastHis').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#PastHistoryMain').show();
    }else  if($('#chkSQ').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#SqQuestionMain').show();
    }

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: please..post your code on jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Use this .. If you use else if only one statement is executed so you should go for if for each and every checkbox

```
    if ($('#chkOTP').is(':checked')) {
        $('#OTPMain').show();
    } 
    if ($('#chkVoicePrint').is(':checked')) {
        $('#VoicePrintEmailCampMain').show();
    } 
    if ($('#chkPersonInfo').is(':checked')) {
        $('#RandomAuthMain').show();
    } 
    if ($('#chkPastHis').is(':checked')) {
        $('#PastHistoryMain').show();
    } 
    if ($('#chkSQ').is(':checked')) {
        $('#SqQuestionMain').show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise,  I tried but the thing is if I am un checking  one check box in multiple factor and changing the drop down to single factor the issue is two divs are getting displayed

Comment: Where did you added this code ..?? Add it in drop down onChange event

Comment: I think what he's saying is your code has no way of hiding the divs if a value changes.

Comment: It should be hided if he added it onChange .. I dont know where he used this code then how could i help him properly

Comment: $('#OTPMain').hide();
    $('#VoicePrintEmailCampMain').hide();
     $('#RandomAuthMain').hide();
      $('#PastHistoryMain').hide();
      $('#SqQuestionMain').hide();
    if($('#chkOTP').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#OTPMain').show();
    } if($('#chkVoicePrint').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#VoicePrintEmailCampMain').show();
    } if($('#chkPersonInfo').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#RandomAuthMain').show();
    } if($('#chkPastHis').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#PastHistoryMain').show();
    }  if($('#chkSQ').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#SqQuestionMain').show();
    }

Comment: I tried the above code it's working fine thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a little bit of forethought can save you a fair bit of code. putting a class on your divs that matches the value of the checkbox you can just do an on click in jQuery like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="first">First<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="second">Second<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="third">Third<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="fourth">Fourth<br />
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second">second</div>
<div class="third">third</div>
<div class="fourth">fourth</div>



$('input:checkbox').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('.'+$(this).val()).show();
    } else {
        $('.'+$(this).val()).hide();
    }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/jRZBX/1/

Comment: @Vignesh '.' + $(this).val(); // this will do like this if clicked div with class first>> `.first`